# Counting frequency of values in recarray of object datatype

Tags: object, numpy, types, frequency, recarray

Here's my input:

```
data = np.array ([( 'a1' , np.NaN , 'a2' ), 
                  ( 'a1' , 'b2' , 'b1' ),  
                  ( 'c1' , 'c1' , np.NaN )], 
                 dtype = [( 'A' , object ), 
                          ( 'B' , object ), 
                          ( 'C' , object )] ).view (np.recarray)
```

I want to count the frequency of each value a variable takes and I want the output to look something like ( say for the input `freq('A')` ):

```
array [ ( 'a1' , 2 ) , ( 'c1' , 1 ) ]
```

I've tried `np.bincounts()` but apparently it doesn't work for object datatypes. Is there a way to achieve this using NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.unique` to assign an integer "label" to each object in `data['A']`. Then you can apply `np.bincount` to the `label`s:

```
In [18]: uniq, label = np.unique(data['A'], return_inverse=True)

In [19]: np.column_stack([uniq, np.bincount(label)])
Out[19]: 
array([['a1', 2],
       ['c1', 1]], dtype=object)
```

Note that operations on NumPy arrays of dtype `object` are no faster (and often are slower) than equivalent operations on lists. (You need to use arrays with native NumPy (i.e. non-object) dtypes to enjoy any speed advantage over pure Python.) For example, your computation may be faster if you use a dict of lists for `data`, and count the frequency with `collections.Counter`:

```
In [21]: data = {'A':['a1','a1','c1']}

In [22]: import collections

In [23]: collections.Counter(data['A'])
Out[23]: Counter({'a1': 2, 'c1': 1})
```

---

As hpaulj points out, you could use `collection.Counter(data['A'])` when `data` is a recarray too. It is faster than the `np.unique`/`np.bincount` method shown above. So that might be your best option if you must use a recarray of objects.

---

Here is a benchmark showing the relative speeds:

```
data = np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], size=(300,)).astype(
    [('A', object), ('B', object), ('C', object)]).view(np.recarray)
data2 = {key:data[key].tolist() for key in ['A','B','C']}
```

Using `Counter` on a dict of lists is fastest:

```
In [92]: %timeit collections.Counter(data2['A'])
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.7 µs per loop
```

Using `Counter` on an array of dtype `object` is next fastest:

```
In [91]: %timeit collections.Counter(data['A'])
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 µs per loop
```

My original suggestion is downright slow (though this is an apples-to-oranges comparison since this returns an array, not a dict):

```
In [93]: %%timeit 
   ....: uniq, label = np.unique(data['A'], return_inverse=True)
   ....: np.column_stack([uniq, np.bincount(label)])
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
```

Comment: `Counter(data['A'])` works if `data` is the recarray.  In other words, it works on a 1d array of objects.  `Counter(np.array(data.tolist(),object).ravel())` is needed to count the whole array (i.e. convert to 2d array of objects and flatten).

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. That's certainly better than the `unique/bincount` method I suggested.